# Saving Sum of List and Displaying it In Another Page Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I want to add items to a list of ints, display the sum of that list in another class, and save that sum in SharedPreferences because I want that sum to be displayed (and change based on more items added from another class). I am not sure how to do it. Here's my add function:

```
  class One{
    List<int> statTotal = [];
    function(){onPressed() => statTotal.add(
                                 int.parse(myInt));}} //this int would always be a different one
```

And now another class on another page should get that int and add it onto some empty list and display the sum of all of those items:

```
class Two{
List<int> total = [];
OrderStats({this.total});
//and then display it below in build
build:
Text(widget.totalz.toString())
```

As I said, I am really not sure how to save the current value of the sum and have it displayed in the second screen until it is changed again when new values are added from the first page. Let me know if I explained it properly, it's  a bit messy I know, but I'm not sure how to finish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my package [rx_shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/rx_shared_preferences).

- Screen1:

```dart
onPressed() {
    statTotal.add(int.parse(myInt));
    RxSharedPreferences.getInstance()
       .setInt("sum_key", statTotal.fold(0, (acc, e) => acc+ e));
}
```

- Screen2:

```dart
StreamBuilder<int>(
    stream: RxSharedPreferences.getInstance().getIntStream("sum_key"),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
       return Text(snapshot.data?.toString() ?? "Loading...");
    }
)
```

Comment: Oh, that's a great solution, didn't think of it going to stream, can't wait to try it out. Thanks a lot and great package!